# Zip function is not working as expected in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, zip

I have these two lists with the same 227 elements:

```
Lc = ['0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0590', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0591', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0592', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0594', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0595', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0596', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597', '0597']
Le = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010', '011', '012', '013', '016', '017', '018', '019', '061', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '122', '123', '124', '125', '819', '820', '821', '822', '823', '824', '825', '826', '827', '828', '829', '830', '831', '832', '833', '834', '835', '836', '837', '838', '839', '840', '841', '842', '843', '850', '851', '021', '025', '201', '202', '203', '204', '205', '206', '208', '209', '211', '212', '213', '214', '215', '216', '217', '218', '219', '220', '221', '222', '223', '224', '225', '226', '227', '228', '229', '820', '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '006', '007', '008', '009', '010', '011', '012', '013', '015', '016', '017', '019', '020', '023', '999', '401', '402', '403', '404', '405', '406', '407', '408', '410', '411', '412', '414', '415', '416', '417', '418', '419', '420', '421', '422', '423', '424', '426', '427', '428', '429', '431', '432', '433', '434', '435', '436', '437', '438', '441', '442', '443', '444', '445', '446', '447', '448', '449', '450', '451', '454', '455', '456', '457', '458', '459', '460', '463', '501', '502', '503', '504', '507', '508', '509', '510', '511', '512', '514', '515', '516', '517', '518', '519', '520', '521', '522', '523', '525', '602', '603', '604', '605', '607', '608', '609', '610', '612', '613', '614', '615', '616', '617', '618', '620', '621', 'AL', 'EF', 'EI', 'FI', 'FR', 'MU', 'PRI', 'PT', '001', '002', '003', '004', '005', '011', '012', '013', '014', '015']
```

I wanted two join it into a dictionary and i used the zip() function:

```
Dce = dict(zip(Lc,Le))
```

I expected that the first element of *Lc* and the first element of *Le* would be the first pair  {key:value} of the dictionary and then so on, resulting a dictionary 227 length but instead, i got this result and i have no idea why

```
{'0590': '851', '0591': '820', '0592': '999', '0594': '463', '0595': '525', '0596': '621', '0597': '015'}
```

Comment: Wait what is the expected output?

Comment: `dict` objects map a *unique key* to arbitrary values. This has nothing to do with `zip`, this is how `dict` objects work.

Comment: List `Lc` contains duplicates and you're using this list as keys in your dictionary. Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

Comment: maybe you need Dce = dict(zip(Le,Lc)) ?

Comment: Even if `Le` is supposed to be the keys why would you even have those as keys? theyre consecutive numbers... That's just a glorified list...

Comment: I'm curious to know what you expect `Dce['0590']` to be.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and Andrej Kesely you are right, it was about the duplicates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i just solved the problem.
I tried to join two list where the values of the keys repeats, and this is not possible for a dictionary, if you see the result, each key has the last value of the iteration and only one.
Instead to join the lists into a dictionary i did it into a list and the result was the expected

```
[('0590', '001'), ('0590', '002'), ('0590', '003'), ('0590', '004'), ('0590', '005'), ('0590', '006'), ('0590', '007'), ('0590', '008'), ('0590', '009'), ('0590', '010'), ('0590', '011'), ('0590', '012'), ('0590', '013'), ('0590', '016'), ('0590', '017'), ('0590', '018'), ('0590', '019'), ('0590', '061'), ('0590', '101'), ('0590', '102'), ('0590', '103'), ('0590', '104'), ('0590', '105'), ('0590', '106'), ('0590', '107'), ('0590', '108'), ('0590', '110'), ('0590', '111'), ('0590', '112'), ('0590', '113'), ('0590', '114'), ('0590', '115'), ('0590', '116'), ('0590', '117'), ('0590', '118'), ('0590', '119'), ('0590', '120'), ('0590', '122'), ('0590', '123'), ('0590', '124'), ('0590', '125'), ('0590', '819'), ('0590', '820'), ('0590', '821'), ('0590', '822'), ('0590', '823'), ('0590', '824'), ('0590', '825'), ('0590', '826'), ('0590', '827'), ('0590', '828'), ('0590', '829'), 
    ('0590', '830'), ('0590', '831'), ('0590', '832'), ('0590', '833'), ('0590', '834'), ('0590', '835'), ('0590', '836'), ('0590', '837'), ('0590', '838'), ('0590', '839'), ('0590', '840'), ('0590', '841'), ('0590', '842'), ('0590', '843'), ('0590', '850'), ('0590', '851'), ('0591', '021'), ('0591', '025'), ('0591', '201'), ('0591', '202'), ('0591', '203'), ('0591', '204'), ('0591', '205'), ('0591', '206'), ('0591', '208'), ('0591', '209'), ('0591', '211'), ('0591', '212'), ('0591', '213'), ('0591', '214'), ('0591', '215'), ('0591', '216'), ('0591', '217'), ('0591', '218'), ('0591', '219'), ('0591', '220'), ('0591', '221'), ('0591', '222'), ('0591', '223'), ('0591', '224'), ('0591', '225'), ('0591', '226'), ('0591', '227'), ('0591', '228'), ('0591', '229'), ('0591', '820'), ('0592', '001'), ('0592', '002'), ('0592', '003'), ('0592', '004'), ('0592', '005'), ('0592', '006'), ('0592', '007'), ('0592', '008'), ('0592', '009'), ('0592', '010'), ('0592', '011'), ('0592', '012'), ('0592', '013'), ('0592', '015'), ('0592', '016'), ('0592', '017'), ('0592', '019'), ('0592', '020'), ('0592', '023'), ('0592', '999'), ('0594', '401'), ('0594', '402'), ('0594', '403'), ('0594', '404'), ('0594', '405'), ('0594', '406'), ('0594', '407'), ('0594', '408'), ('0594', '410'), ('0594', '411'), ('0594', '412'), ('0594', '414'), ('0594', '415'), ('0594', '416'), ('0594', '417'), ('0594', '418'), ('0594', '419'), ('0594', '420'), ('0594', '421'), ('0594', '422'), ('0594', '423'), ('0594', '424'), ('0594', '426'), ('0594', '427'), ('0594', '428'), ('0594', '429'), ('0594', '431'), ('0594', '432'), ('0594', '433'), ('0594', '434'), ('0594', '435'), ('0594', '436'), ('0594', '437'), ('0594', '438'), ('0594', '441'), ('0594', '442'), ('0594', '443'), ('0594', '444'), ('0594', '445'), ('0594', '446'), ('0594', '447'), ('0594', '448'), ('0594', '449'), ('0594', '450'), ('0594', '451'), ('0594', '454'), ('0594', '455'), ('0594', '456'), ('0594', 
    '457'), ('0594', '458'), ('0594', '459'), ('0594', '460'), ('0594', '463'), ('0595', '501'), ('0595', '502'), ('0595', '503'), ('0595', '504'), ('0595', '507'), ('0595', '508'), ('0595', '509'), ('0595', '510'), ('0595', '511'), ('0595', '512'), ('0595', '514'), ('0595', '515'), ('0595', '516'), ('0595', '517'), ('0595', '518'), ('0595', '519'), ('0595', '520'), ('0595', '521'), ('0595', '522'), ('0595', '523'), ('0595', '525'), ('0596', '602'), ('0596', '603'), ('0596', '604'), ('0596', '605'), ('0596', '607'), ('0596', '608'), ('0596', '609'), ('0596', '610'), ('0596', '612'), ('0596', '613'), ('0596', '614'), ('0596', '615'), ('0596', '616'), ('0596', '617'), ('0596', '618'), ('0596', '620'), ('0596', '621'), ('0597', 'AL'), ('0597', 'EF'), ('0597', 'EI'), ('0597', 'FI'), ('0597', 'FR'), ('0597', 'MU'), ('0597', 'PRI'), ('0597', 'PT'), ('0597', '001'), ('0597', '002'), 
    ('0597', '003'), ('0597', '004'), ('0597', '005'), ('0597', '011'), ('0597', '012'), ('0597', '013'), ('0597', '014'), ('0597', '015')]
```

Thanks a lot.